# Textures Not Working In .jar File After Export. But Worked Before

Tags: java, eclipse, export, textures

Ok So Ive Been Searching For Months Now And People Have Asked This Question MANY Times But The Answer They Get Isnt Simple Enough For Me To Understand. So I Made A Tower Defence Game In Java. I Can Run It In Eclipse Without A Problem. But Once I Export It In ANY Way (Executable Or Not) I Can Open It And IT Opens, But Theres No Textures. Ive Exstracted The .jar And The Textures Are There. The Answer I Found Was To Put

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

But Where Do I Put That?!?!??! My Texture Finder Thing That I Use And It Works When I Launch it In Eclipse Is:

```
tileset_res[2] = new ImageIcon("res/coin.png").getImage();
```

Ok SO Where Do i 
Put The `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);` ??